# finding minimal path with networkx where the weights are the nodes

Tags: networkx

I have a graph in networkx where each node is a number. for example:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edge(10, 20)
```

I want to find a minimal patch between two nodes, where the weights are the nodes themselves.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the Graph into a `DiGraph` (`H = G.to_directed()`), and assign the weight of each node to all edges originating from that node (`for target in H[source]: H[source][target]['weight'] = node_weight`). Then you can use `path = nx.shortest_path(source, target, weight='weight')` as per usual.